# How are applications able to unmute system sound, and how to prevent it?

Tags: macos, audio, permission

I've noticed that applications and even websites have the ability to unmute macOS system sound. Long ago for example, I noticed Spotify was able to unmute during ads. On the apple community forums, [another user reports similar-sounding behavior](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7522229) with some "me too" clicks but no resolution.

The specific reproducible case which I'd like to understand:

- Firefox 111 on macOS 13.1
- Play a video on hulu.com with ads
- Mute the system sound when an ad starts
- The site/video/browser unmutes the system when the next ad or the show starts

How can I narrow down if this is a web APIs is Hulu using to ask browsers to unmute or if I can change anything on my system side to  prevent this?